# Parsing JSON in Ruby (like XPATH)

Tags: ruby, json

I have a JSON document returned from a query to the Google Books API, e.g:

> {
>    "items": [
>     {
>      "volumeInfo": {
>       "industryIdentifiers": [
>        {
>         "type": "OTHER",
>         "identifier": "OCLC:841804665"
>        }
>       ]
>      }
>     },
>     {
>      "volumeInfo": {
>       "industryIdentifiers": [
>        {
>         "type": "ISBN_10",
>         "identifier": "156898118X"...

I need the ISBN number (type: ISBN_10 or ISBN_13) and I've written a simple loop that traverses the parsed JSON (`parsed = json.parse(my_uri_response)`).  In this loop, I have a `next if k['type'] = "OTHER"` which sets "type" to "OTHER".

How do I best extract just one ISBN number from my JSON example?  Not all of them, just one.

Something like XPath search would be helpful.

Comment: That's because you do `k['type'] = "OTHER"` rather than `k['type'] == "OTHER"`, notice the single vs double equals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about:

```
parsed['items'].map { |book| 
  book['volume_info']['industryIdentifiers'].find{ |prop| 
    ['ISBN_10', 'ISBN_13'].include? prop['type']
  }['identifier'] 
}
```

If you receive `undefined method [] for nil:NilClass` this means that you have an element within `items` array, which has no `volume_info` key, or that you have a volume with a set of `industryIdentifiers` without ISBN. Code below should cover all those cases (+ the case when you have `volumeInfo` without `industry_identifiers`:

```
parsed['items'].map { |book| 
  identifiers = book['volume_info'] && book['volume_info']['industryIdentifiers']
  isbn_identifier = idetifiers && identifiers.find{ |prop| 
    ['ISBN_10', 'ISBN_13'].include? prop['type']}['identifier']
  }
  isbn_identifier && isbn_identifier['identifier']
}.compact
```

If you happen to have the `andand` gem, this might be written as:

```
parsed['items'].map { |book| 
  book['volume_info'].andand['industryIdentifiers'].andand.find{ |prop| 
    ['ISBN_10', 'ISBN_13'].include? prop['type']
  }.andand['identifier'] 
}.compact
```

Note that this will return only one ISBN for each volume. If you have volumes with both `ISBN_10` and `ISBN_13` and you want to get both, instead of `find` you'll need to use `select` method and `.map{|i| i[:identifier]}` in place of `.andand['identifier']`.

Answer (score 6):

[JSONPath](https://github.com/joshbuddy/jsonpath) may be just what you're looking for:

```
require 'jsonpath'

json = #your raw JSON above

path = JsonPath.new('$..industryIdentifiers[?(@.type == "ISBN_10")].identifier')

puts path.on(json)
```

Result:

```
156898118X
```

See [this page](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) for how XPath translates to JSONPath. It helped me determine the JSONPath above.

Comment: Have you tested this? As mentioned here: https://github.com/joshbuddy/jsonpath/issues/17 string functions aren't implemented...

Comment: They're not, which is why I used a 'script expression' and Ruby syntax inside the `?( )` instead of XPath style expressions.